# Ожидание по времени

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток. Сейчас изучаю Java и решил написать программку. Начал недавно, поэтому и прога следовательно простая. Решил сделать так называемый секундомер. Если это имеет значение, работаю в эклипсе. Столкнулся с незнанием параметра ожидания. То есть как сделать, чтобы программа с переодичностью в 1 секунду выдавала мне число? Начало кода

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1;
    while(a < 60) {
        System.out.println(a);
        a++;
    }
}
```

Как сделать ожидание?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На данный момент рекомендуется использовать не Thread.sleep, а TimeUnit.
Итак, код:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class Stopwatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 1; i < 60; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно то, что нужно было!

Comment: В чем его преимущество перед классическим Thread.sleep() ?

Comment: Я не увидел, но человек полностью написал простой и понятный (для меня) код. По аналогии с его кодом понял, как использовать Thread.sleep

Comment: mikillskegg, преимуществ в общем-то никаких, разве что явное указание единиц времени. По факту, это и есть обёртка над Thread.sleep(). Я просто говорю, как и писал выше, что рекомендован к использованию.

Comment: Ругается на sleep помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так (используя класс java.util.Timer):

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ReminderBeep {
  Toolkit toolkit;

  Timer timer;

  public ReminderBeep(int seconds)
  {
    toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), (seconds+1) * 1000, seconds * 1000); //вешаем задание таймеру (второй аргумент - через сколько всё начнётся, а третий - интервал, каждые seconds секунд таймер будет запускать метод run())
  }

  class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("3 секунды прошло!");
      toolkit.beep(); //подаём звуковой сигнал
      //если таймер нужно остановить, то:
          //timer.cancel(); или
          //System.exit(0); завершает поток, в котором идёт выполнение
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Выполнение метода каждые 3 секунды.");
    new ReminderBeep(3);
    System.out.println("Сейчас начнется :)");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thread.sleep(1000) как самый очевидный вариант.

Comment: А в какую именно часть кода нужно поставить? уже находил, но только не понял как пользоваться :(

Comment: А где вам нужно ждать? В вашем варианте сразу после while(a<60).

Comment: я хочу чтобы было так: я задаю количество секунд, которое он должен отсчитать и после каждого напечатывания переменной он ждем одну секунду, то есть какбы печатает число +1 каждую секунду. Такой вот простой секундомер.

Comment: Ну так и должно будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

[Ссылка на документацию](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Comment: Thread.Sleep() - замораживает весь поток, я так думаю лучше асинхронный вариант.

Comment: а нам что нужно? Sleep можно использовать и нужно даже. Вот только не стоит использовать в главном потоке, если он GUI.

Comment: Методы в Java называются с маленькой буквы, поэтому метода `Sleep()` у класса `Thread` нет.