# Помогите с реализацией игры

Tags: java, javafx, разработка-игр

Суть игры заключается в том, что есть 3 круга красного цвета, случайным образом выбирается один из них и закрашивается в зеленый. В течении определенного промежутка времени (который постепенно будет уменьшаться) необходимо клацнуть на него мышкой, если этого не происходит, выбирается другой случайный круг. Собственно, я не знаю как реализовать эти промежутки времени и не знаю как сделать, чтобы игра длилась определенное время. Вот, что у меня есть на данный момент

```
package yourreaction;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Random;

public class YourReaction extends Application {
    Scene scene;
    VBox vbox;
    final int AmountOfCircles = 9;
    final int radius = 20;
    int score = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Hello World!");

        vbox = new VBox(5);

        scene = new Scene(vbox, 300, 250);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        Button B_Start = new Button("Start");
        Button B_Exit  = new Button("Exit");

        B_Start.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                GameProcess();
            }
        });

        B_Exit.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
            public void handle(MouseEvent me)  {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(B_Start, B_Exit);

        stage.show();
    }

    public int GameProcess() {
        vbox.getChildren().clear();

        Random random = new Random();

        HBox hbox = new HBox(5);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        scene.setRoot(hbox);

        Circle circle1 = new Circle(radius, Color.RED);
        Circle circle2 = new Circle(radius, Color.RED);
        Circle circle3 = new Circle(radius, Color.RED);

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(circle1, circle2, circle3);

        //while(true) {
            int RandomNum = 1 + random.nextInt(3);

            if(RandomNum == 1) circle1.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            if(RandomNum == 2) circle2.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            if(RandomNum == 3) circle3.setFill(Color.GREEN);

            circle1.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
                public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                    circle1.setFill(Color.RED);
                    score++;
                }
            });

            circle2.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
                public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                    circle2.setFill(Color.RED);
                    score++;
                }
            });

            circle3.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
                public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                    circle3.setFill(Color.RED);
                    score++;
                }
            });
        //}

        return score;
    }
}
```

Comment: прочитайте про разделение модели и отображения, например паттерн MVC. а так же соглашение о коде (code convention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В создании этой игры, Вам не обойтись без использования нескольких потоков. Внимательно изучите тему многопоточности в java; обратите свое внимание на метод `.sleep()`. Вероятнее всего Вам нужно будет запустить ваш цикл в потоке таким образом чтобы на каждой итерации количество миллисекунд "пауза" уменьшалось.

Это, в некотором роде, может послужить примером:
[ожидание по времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/49432/%D0%9E%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8).

Что бы игра длилась определённое время используй `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Метод вернёт тебе переменную типа long, это количество миллисекунд прошедших с 1 января 1970 по текущий момент (вызов метода). Добавь условие для выхода:

```
 if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= timeIsOut){ break }
```

где `timeIsOut` твоя переменная long которая указывает на время по достижению которого игра должна завершиться. Поток можно прервать методом `interrupt()`, но будьте осторожны, внезапное завершение потока может быть [небезопасным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467224/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA).
Здесь я не совсем уверен что использование `System.currentTimeMillis()` - лучший вариант. Но, считаю что после изучения темы потоков Вы сможете найти своё "лучшее решение". Не лишним будет посмотреть класс `Calendar()` хм.. `Calendar.getInstance()`.